# PHP- set chmod after successfully upload?

Tags: php, permissions, chmod

```
<?php

if (isset($_FILES['datei']))
{
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['datei']['tmp_name'], 'upload/'.$_FILES['datei']['name']);

echo "Filee successfully uploaded.";

chmod($_FILES["datei"]["name"], 777);

echo "<p> Chmod successfully set!<br>";
} 

?>
```

The upload works, but the chmod isn't set. Can anyone help out and check the code ?

Comment: Are you running Apache as a sudoer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have an absolute path to your file.
For example:

```
chmod("/var/www/files/uploads/" . $_FILES["datei"]["name"] . ".jpg", 0777)
```

Make sure the file location actually exists. The cheap and dirty way to do this:

```
if(!file_exists("/var/www/files/uploads/" . $_FILES["datei"]["name"] . ".jpg")) {
  die("File not found with path: /var/www/files/uploads/" . $_FILES["datei"]["name"] . ".jpg");
}
```

EDIT: also, on Aquillo answer, it should be 0777.

Comment: Thanks, all anwsers worked for me and thanks for the advice with the 0777 permission.

Answer (score 1):

You move the file to `'upload/'.$_FILES['datei']['name']` but chmod `$_FILES['datei']['name']`. Note you've been missing the `upload/'. Change the chmod to:

```
chmod('upload/'.$_FILES['datei']['name'], 0777);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set the chmod as

```
chmod($_FILES["datei"]["name"], 0777);
```

You can read more about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php).

Comment: Apache runs with easyscp not as root.
0777 doesnt change the permission.

Comment: Probably due to multiple mistakes. A) using decimal instead of octal. B) you moved the file but the path seems not to be set accordingly (as others mentioned).

Answer (score 0):

you need to prefix mode with a zero (0), so

```
mode should be 0777
chmod($_FILES["datei"]["name"], 0777); //correct way of mode
```